# In spotfire - html page tab view

Tags: spotfire

I want to implement a HTML page tab view (attached the sample image:page tab view.jpg) in the spotfire text area. On click of the menu in the Tab view, the visualization has to be shown.

Pasted the HTML, CSS and JS code below. If you save it as a html file to your desktop and open it, you could easily understand my requirement.

I know the styles can be added as part of HTML tags but i am not sure whether the level of css styles mentioned in the html code shown below can be included as part of the html tag in spotfire. also i am not sure how to pass the control from text area when clicked on a menu option and show the visualisation.

could anyone please share any video link or sample code or documentation how this is achieved in spotfire?

[Page Tab View Sample Picture. Want to achieve this in Spotfire](https://i.stack.imgur.com/taiGh.jpg)

```js
<script>
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
</script>
```

```css
<style>
body {font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;}

ul.tab {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Float the list items side by side */
ul.tab li {float: left;}

/* Style the links inside the list items */
ul.tab li a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change background color of links on hover */
ul.tab li a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
ul.tab li a:focus, .active {
    background-color: #ccc;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
    display: none;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-top: none;
}
</style>
<body>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<ul class="tab">
  <li><a href="#" class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')">London</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')">Paris</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')">Tokyo</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="London" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>London</h3>
  <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
</div>

<div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Paris</h3>
  <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p>
</div>

<div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Tokyo</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>


     
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm working on this @pradeep but haven't been able to get it like you want it.

Comment: Thanks SCSimon for your effort. May i know whether you have any sample dxp file available to understand how to pass the control from HTML to JS when clicked an menu item or any button?